# How to access a variable content from HTML to controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller

```
 <tr ng-repeat="baseline in tower.baselines"></tr>
```

I have above HTML code where i have been using the ng-repeat to get to store the distorted array into an variable baseline....how can i access the same variable into controller?

Comment: You can pass it to controller via `ng-init='vm.pass(baseline)'`

Comment: Can't tell if you are looking for the $scope variable or $index for ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <p>{{baseline.doSomething($index)}}</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-repeat variable ($index) in the html and call a function on the controller

```
<div ng-repeat="baseline in tower.baselines">
    <div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
        <p>{{baseline.doSomething($index)}}</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```